# Jquery, on parent click check child

Tags: jquery

How can i do the action after click on "child_good", but not on click on 'child_wrong'. But the event onClick must be on 'parent'.

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child_wrong"></div>
    <div class="child_good"></div>
</div>

<script>
    $('.parent').on('click', function(){

        if($(this).hasClass('child_good')) {
            alert(1);
        }
        return false;
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Use  `$(event.target)` to check the class of clicked element.

```js
$('.parent').on('click', function(event){
    if($(event.target).hasClass('child_good')) {
       alert(1);
    }
    return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child_wrong">aaa</div>
    <div class="child_good">bbb</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can delegate event to parent using [Event Delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/).

```js
$('.parent').on('click', '.child_good', function(event){
    alert(1);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child_wrong">aaa</div>
    <div class="child_good">bbb</div>
</div>
```

Comment: i dont get the downvote this should work [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/b9hfogrd/)

Comment: @guradio, Demo added

Comment: it was just a missing comma and they already down voted.. sad